# Does strict contraction lead to convergence to zero in norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, contraction-operator

In my functional analysis class I was asked this question which got me stuck:

> Let $ \mathbb{H} $ be a Hilbert space and we are given an operator T satisfying:
>
> $ || T || < 1 $ in the operator norm. We are asked if the following necessarily is true: for all $ h \in \mathbb{H} $ does one have the convergence to zero $ T^nh \to 0 $ in the Hilbert space norm?

I cannot really think of any counterexamples or how to prove it is true so I need help and am asking here. Thanks to all helpers.

Comment: Could you prove it if you wrote $\|T\| = 0.9$ instead? If so, adapt this to the general case. If not, think about what $\|T^2 h\|$ is.

Comment: @T.Bongers : I think I can prove it then thanks for the advice